# Nat skin with tinymce as the editor

Tags: tinymce, themes, twiki

How can I have NAT Skin with TinyMCE as the editor in twiki. When I changed my skin to Nat in the twiki preferences my editor automatically got changed to natedit though i was working previously on tinymce editor and would like to do so in the future but with nat as the default skin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer. This is a bug in TWiki and will remain so. What we can do is to shift to its fork FosWiki for the bug have been long solved in there.